# save html page in pdf format in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, pdf, save

I want to have a save page button on my site to allow users to just download the page that they are on.

is there like an ng-save that i can use or something?

Comment: AFAIK, `alert("Press Ctrl + P to save current page")` is the best option

Answer (score 0):

As you've tagged PDF, I'm assuming that you're looking to save the page in a PDF format. If so, you might want to take a look at PhantomJS, which has an option to save as PDF:

http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html